# how to rotate CALayer at one point

Tags: iphone, core-animation

how to rotate CALayer at one selected point.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, rotationPoint.x-center.x, rotationPoint.y-center.y, 0.0);
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rotationAngle, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, center.x-rotationPoint.x, center.y-rotationPoint.y, 0.0);
```

Where `center` is the center of your layer, `rotationAngle` is in radians (positive is counterclockwise), and `rotationPoint` is the point about which you wish to rotate. `center` and `rotationPoint` are in the coordinate space of the containing view.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

1. Define your sublayer that you want to rotate;
2. Set its `bounds`, `position` in superlayer and `anchorPoint`. `anchorPoint` has relative coordinates and points to an `anchorPoint`. Your sublayer will rotate around this `anchorPoint`;
3. Add transformation.

For example, to rotate a sublayer on its superview top center point around sublayer's bottom center, use this code:

```
    // 1
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                      y: 0,
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
    let sublayer = CAShapeLayer()
    sublayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    sublayer.path = path.cgPath
    superlayer.addSublayer(sublayer)

    // 2
    sublayer.bounds = rect
    sublayer.position = CGPoint(x: superlayer.bounds.size.width/2, y: 0)
    sublayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)

    // 3
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.toValue = 2*CGFloat.pi
    rotationAnimation.duration = 3
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    sublayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: not sure why (maybe because of coordinate system mislead), but suggested code works only if I change `anchorPoint` to `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)`
thanks for the detailed answer, much useful

Comment: Adding an Animation with `forKey` as `nil` is going to increase memory usage if this is used more than once

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CA documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html).

You want to set the transform to a CATransform3DRotate, for example:

```
CATransform3D current = myLayer.transform;
myLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(current, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(20), 0, 1.0, 0);
```

Comment: This will only suffice for rotating the layer about its current center, not an arbitrary point.