# How to rotate a CAShapeLayer along with its Pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, transform, calayer

I have a CAShapeLayer, I am able to rotate it using UIRotationGestureRecognizer. But when rotating, it only rotate its frame not the filled pattern inside it.

```
        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [finalShapeLayersArray objectAtIndex:indextobeRotated];
        CGPathRef path = createPathRotatedAroundBoundingBoxCenter(shapeLayer.path,recognizer.rotation);
        shapeLayer.path  = path;
        CGPathRelease(path);
        recognizer.rotation = 0;
```

Bu doing this, it only rotates the boundary of the CAShapeLayer. I have filled a pattern with an image. I just want that pattern should also be rotated.

Comment: That's not enough information to answer your question. You need to **edit your question** and update with a more detailed description of your setup, preferably with code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a *rotation transform* on your layer using [CALayer's `transform` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/transform) instead (you do not rotate the the shape path then as the whole layer will be rotated).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929703/400056) on how to create such a transform. Also see the [Core Animation Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html) for all the functions that can create/modify transformations.