# CALayer Rotation around center

Tags: swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I wanna do something like round progress bar, drawing bezier path in UIView, but it appears rotated by PI/2. So I need to rotate it by PI/2. Problem is, that it is rotating around some very strange point, and I don’t know how to deal with it.
I tried to follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926923/how-to-rotate-calayer-at-one-point) instructions, but it doesn’t help, because I wanna rotate it around center.
Here is my code:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    ringLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    ringLayerBackground = CAShapeLayer()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    ringLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapButt
    ringLayer.fillColor = nil
    ringLayerBackground.lineCap = kCALineCapButt
    ringLayerBackground.fillColor = nil
    ringLayerBackground.strokeColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.1).CGColor
    }


override func layoutSubviews() {
    layer.addSublayer(ringLayer)
    layer.addSublayer(ringLayerBackground)
    addSubview(imageView)
    let rectForRing = CGRectInset(bounds, lineWidth/2, lineWidth/2)        
    //ringLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5))
    ringLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(ringLayer.transform, CGFloat(-M_PI/20), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    //Tried both ways
    ringLayer.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(rectForRing, nil)
    ringLayerBackground.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(rectForRing, nil)
    super.layoutSubviews()
    }
```

[Here is what I’m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDcmr.png)

I know there are a lot of similar question, but they don’t help.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Found magic number, that works on iPhone 6: 140

```
let o = 140.0
ringLayer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(ringLayer.transform, CGFloat(o), CGFloat(o), 0)
ringLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(ringLayer.transform, CGFloat(-M_PI/2), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
ringLayer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(ringLayer.transform, CGFloat(-o), CGFloat(-o), 0)
```

Works fine, but I can’t guess where that number comes from.

**UPDATE**
Solved it. It was thing in `ringLayer.position`, need to set it to the centre of view. After that, I made rect for bezier path so, that its center is the same with `ringLayer.position`. So code became complex, solution from @chrisco is much more applicable.

Comment: Read the CALayer documentation on anchorPoint, it defines the origin for location and rotations.

Comment: @chrisco changing anchorpoint makes absolutely no difference, I don’t know why. Changing anchorpoint of super layer moves it.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is draw a circular progress bar, then just create a UIBezier path with the method init(arcCenter center: CGPoint,
        radius radius: CGFloat,
    startAngle startAngle: CGFloat,
      endAngle endAngle: CGFloat,
     clockwise clockwise: Bool) -> UIBezierPath .  If you want the progress to start at the top, use a start angle of -M_PI_2, end angle of 3 * M_PI_2, clockwise=true, assign the path to a shape layer, given it stroke color, width etc, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you @AlfredZien. The position thing solved it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your problem, but not your immediate question:

```
var progreessLayer = CAShapeLayer()
// add layer to your view etc

var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
    radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2),
    endAngle: CGFloat(3 * M_PI_2), clockwise: true)
progreessLayer.path = path.CGPath
progreessLayer.lineWidth = 10
progreessLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
progreessLayer.fillColor = nil
```